# URI::InvalidComponentError (bad component(expected scheme component): : https):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, devise

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails web app and I'm using Devise for user/password and OmniAuth for authentication using social media accounts. And I'm also using Nginx.

Authentication with username/password worked perfectly. But when I added ssl certificate to Nginx. I'm now able to login. But when I logout I get the error message in the title `URI::InvalidComponentError (bad component(expected scheme component): : https):` and telling that I have an exception generated from:

```
def check_scheme(v)
  if v && parser.regexp[:SCHEME] !~ v
    raise InvalidComponentError,
      "bad component(expected scheme component): #{v}"
  end
```

How can I fix this problem in order for all types of authentications to work?

***UPDATE***

It throws the same exception after almost every redirect withing the web app. But redirects anyway, event user login. But it never logs out

***UPDATE 2 ***

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806828/ruby-on-rails-devise-throwing-exceptions-on-logout-after-configuring-ssl-certi) has more detailed description of my issue

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739109/ruby-on-rails-after-https-http-parse-error-malformed-request-pumahttp) is another try to fix the issue

***UPDATE 3***

When I tried adding `config.force_ssl = true` to my environment `.rb` file, I get "page not found" and the following in `ssl.error.log`

```
2018/04/13 05:05:14 [error] 7317#0: *553 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <my laptop ip>, server: vps37181, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "<domain name>"
2018/04/13 05:05:14 [error] 7317#0: *553 open() "/var/www/<app-name>/public/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: <my laptop ip>, server: vps37181, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "<domain name>"
```

***UPDATE 4***

My current nginx configuration at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf` is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <server-name>;

    client_max_body_size 15M;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      <.pem file path>;
    ssl_certificate_key  <.key file path>;
    ...
    root <"public" directory inside my app directory>;
    access_log <ssl.access.log path>;
    error_log  <ssl.error.log path>;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: $scheme;
 }
```

***UPDATE 5***

After every request redirected from Nginx to the app, I get the following in the app console:

```
Cannot render console from <my laptop ip>! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

URI::InvalidComponentError (bad component(expected scheme component): : https):

/home/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:322:in `check_scheme'
/home/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb:363:in `scheme='
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:17:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:190:in `call!'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call'
omniauth (1.8.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.4.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This message doesn't prevent the website from loading. But when user logs out (I'm using Devise for username/password user authentication). the website throws in the browser the error I mentioned earlier:

```
URI::InvalidComponentError
bad component(expected scheme component): : https
Extracted source (around line #322):

def check_scheme(v)
  if v && parser.regexp[:SCHEME] !~ v
    raise InvalidComponentError, # line 322
      "bad component(expected scheme component): #{v}"
  end
```

and I get the console error message twice.

***UPDATE 7***

I'm running my server in development.

I dug deeper and I found that :

```
URI::InvalidComponentError (bad component(expected scheme component): : https)
```

means that what was expected was `: https` while received `https`.

I tried modifying `parser.regexp[:SCHEME]` in `check_shceme in /home/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/generic.rb` in which it approves `: https` also. But now, on logout, which supposed to send a request to

```
https://<my domain name>/users/log_out
```

now redirectes to :

```
https://<my domain name>/users/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/:%20https://<my domain name>/
```

in which `:%20` means whitespace.

Comment: I would suggest you delete the other question and update everything here, else it would be mess to track and effort wasted for different people. One issue that I see is you had `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000` in your nginx config. This should `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000`, next I would check the omniauth logout config and make sure a http was not hardcoded for logout redirect. Also I will make sure `config.force_ssl = true` is set. Next also make sure you are running with `RAILS_ENV=production` for running it in production mode

Comment: @TarunLalwani , please view ***UPDATE 3 *** section in my question. I also use ```proxy_pass http://...``` now and trying running in production using ``` -e production```

Comment: Can you please update your current nginx config in this question?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added my current nginx config to ***UPDATE 4*** in my question. Please check it

Comment: Please try removing `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` and see if it helps?

Comment: @TarunLalwani . I removed ```proxy_set_header Host $http_host;``` . Same result however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168921/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-tamerb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `destory_user_session` route. Somehow it was overritten by another one.

I (temporarily) fixed my issue by setting the method of `destory_user_session` to `get` instead of `delete` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` using :

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```